# Some not found errors in cmd for install react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Some errors in installing React

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing npx cache? Files are located in %LocalAppData%/npm-cache/_npx.

You can run `npx clear-npx-cache`